# Showing a file in a new browser window django

Tags: python, django, django-views

I am getting a 404 error when i am trying to show the pdf file in a new browser window when the user pushes a HTML button. I cannot see anything wring with the code.but it is not working.

Fist I show and return my path to my pdf

**Views.py**

```
def show_file(response):
pdf = open('myapp/faults.pdf', 'rb') 
response = FileResponse(pdf)
return response
```

**Urls.py**

```
path('show_file', views.show_file),
```

**index.html**

```
<input type="button" value="Show Report" onclick="window.open('show_file')">
```

Comment: does it work if you try to show it in the same window?

Comment: Im not sure how to open to replace the current window. Here in the HTML i have it set to open a new window. with `window.open("show_file")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Urls.py

```
path('show_file/', views.show_file),
```

you have to put slash after your url

Answer (score 0):

`window.open()` needs a URL to open

```
onclick="window.open({% url 'show_file' %})"
```

I think that will do it.